# VIM: Copying Formatting to Visual Selection?

Tags: vim, formatting

I'm not sure if this is possible, but Vim constantly surprises me. What I'd like to be able to do is take the formatting of one block of text and apply it to a selection. Assuming several lines like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Something Here</span><i class="icon"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Something Here</span><i class="icon"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Something Here</span><i class="icon"></i></a></li>
```

I'd like to format one of the lines:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Something Here</span>
        <i class="icon"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

And then apply that formatting to the remaining lines. Again, no clue if this is doable, but it would be very neat if it could - I often have to implement HTML templates where there are long lines that may have 5 or 6 nested tags within, often starting with an indentation that is quite out there.

Comment: did you check the `j` and `:j` ? if you want to do some batch job, consider to make a macro with `search` and `j`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the recording feature of vim? Try to do following:

1. press `q` + `some character` to enter the recording mode
2. do formatting of a line
3. press `q` to exit the recording mode
4. go to the next line
5. press `@` + `some character` to reproduce recorded operations

Comment: This works to some degree, but tabs seem to be completely ignored when replaying the macro.

Comment: I would always use whitespaces instead of tabs. This macro can not  also record mouse operations ))

Comment: @phatskat:  Tabs should be recorded just like other keystrokes in a macro.  I did a little test with your example, and it worked fine.  Perhaps your indenting settings are getting in the way; try `:setl indentexpr= noet` for example.  @freude:  I would switch your steps 3 and 4 so that moving to the next line gets repeated along with the rest of the macro.  After repeating it once, you can even give a count, say `2@@` to do it two more times.

Comment: @freude using whitespace instead of tabs isn't a viable option - it could be used and then replaced with tabs via regular expression, but that almost feels like getting too far away from my original goal. @benjifisher thanks for the tips, but the `setlocal` for `indentexpr` didn't help. I'm sure it's something in my config, and this appears to be the best answer. At least breaking the lines in the proper place is a good first step, and I can tweak my tab settings to see if that helps. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it with a macro for your sample input, add a macro with the following command and run it on a line using `@i` or on multiple lines using `{motion}@i` i.e. to run it on 3 lines press `3@i` and it will indent all 3 lines.

`:let @i='0f<i^M^[>>;i^M^[>>;;i^M^[;;;i^M^[<<;i^M^[<<+'`

Explanation:

1. `0` : Move to the beginning of the line
2. `f<` : Find  first `<`
3. `i^M^[` : Enter Insert Mode, Insert a new-line and go back to command mode.
4. `>>` : Indent the line
5. `;` : Find next `<`
6. `i^M^[` : Repeat step 3
7. `<<` : Un-indent the line
8. `+` : Move to the first non-whitespace character on next line

Comment: Looks nifty, but all I got when using `@i` was the actual "text" content of the register. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @phatskat - I should've mentioned that control keys have to inserted after pressing `Ctrl-v`, so to insert `^M`, type `Ctrl-v + <Enter>`. Similarly for `^[` type, `Ctrl-v + <Esc>`

Comment: Ah that makes a little more sense...let me give it a shot

Comment: that kind of works...I end up with breaks at random places - see http://pastebin.com/SYAXbdAN

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly for the input you've provided. Probably you're missing something

Comment: yep, I turned on `:set compatible` and it looks a lot better than before, so something in my config...or plugins...or who knows what is interfering with it. Thanks for the interesting answer...one day when I figure out what it does I might be able to use it with my settings ;)

Comment: Sure, I'll add a explanation and/or a demo to help you understand it better ;)

Comment: @phatskat - Added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative filter the content with `haml` and `html2haml` commands via `:!`

```
:%!html2haml -s | haml -q -s
```

Install gems via `gem install haml` and `gem install html2haml`

For more help with filters see `:h :range!`

Answer (score 0):

If the input is as regular as show in first post, you can use a regex like this one:

```
:%s/\(<a.\{-}>\)\(<span.\{-}\/span>\)\(<i.\{-}\/i>\)\(<\/a>\)/\r    \1\r
  \2\r        \3\r    \4\r/g
```

The explanation is that you separate each bunch of codes in groups `\(...\)` then at replacement part, add some spaces before each ones.